# Django Queryset Filter Performance Optimization

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm seeing high database CPU utilization based on the following code in my Django app:

```
existing_host = Host.objects.filter(names__contains=[hostname]).first()
```

I have around 300,000 hosts in my database which isn't a huge amount so I'm wondering how I can optimize the performance of this query.  I am using Postgres as the database.

**RDS Performance Insights**
[image]

**SQL**

```
SELECT "hosts_host"."id", "hosts_host"."created", "hosts_host"."last_updated",
"hosts_host"."names", "hosts_host"."domain_id", "hosts_host"."os_id",
"hosts_host"."certificate_id" FROM "hosts_host" WHERE "hosts_host"."names" @> 
ARRAY[?]::varchar(?)[] ORDER BY "hosts_host"."names" ASC LIMIT ?
```

**models.py**

```
class Host(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    names = ArrayField(models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=settings.MAX_CHAR_COUNT), default=list, null=False)
    ip_addresses = models.ManyToManyField(IPAddress)
    services = models.ManyToManyField(Service)
    domain = models.ForeignKey(Domain, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    os = models.ForeignKey(OperatingSystem, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    ciphers = models.ManyToManyField(Cipher, blank=True)
    certificate = models.ForeignKey(Certificate, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['names']

    def __str__(self):
        return "[Host object: id = {}, names = {}, domain = {}]".format(self.id, self.names, self.domain)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "[Host object: id = {}, names = {}, domain = {}]".format(self.id, self.names, self.domain)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Host):
            return sorted(self.names) == sorted(other.names)
        return False

    def __hash__(self) -> int:
        return hash(tuple(sorted(self.names)))

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.names[0] < other.names[0]

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return '/explore/{}/{}'.format(self.domain.name, self.id)
```

Comment: Normally using arrays is nto a good idea. Often it is better to make use of a `ManyToManyField`, since then it filters once on the other table, and performs a JOIN through an index.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks for the info.  Long term my solution is to change the DB schema.  Short term, I'm going to perform this search via Elasticsearch so it doesn't hit the DB.